# Split a SurfaceView - Android/Java

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I'd like to split up a SurfaceView in order to update one part of the screen and not the other one. Is there any way to accomplish that or I need to do two SurfaceView's?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(Rect dirty)` to specify what part of your surface will change (and what part will not).

Assuming your program is updating a `SurfaceHolder` in a loop like below:

```
private boolean mIsRunning;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

// ...

public void run() {
    while (mIsrunning){
        Canvas canvas = null;
        synchronized (mHolder) {
            try {
                canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
                doDraw(canvas);
            }
            finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Replacing `SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas()` with `lockCanvas(Rect dirty)` will only force you to draw with the bounds of `dirty`.  The rest of the holder will be preserved and does not need to be redrawn.